# CSS Link Styling not applying across all browsers

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, styling

I have created a simple webpage, with three links which get the font increased by 110% on hover, these links are also supposed to change colour when mouseover..

In IE these links all function as expected except for the 'Contact Us' link and in Firefox it's behaving opposite, only the first link does not change colour.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ChollUni';
    src: url('fonts/ChollUni.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('fonts/ChollUni.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('fonts/ChollUni.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/ChollUni.svg#ChollUni') format('svg');
         }
#logo {
    padding: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    }
#links {
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin: 10px auto;
    color:#4F91CD;
    font-family: 'ChollUni',Helvetica, san-serif;
    font-size:22px;
    }
#links a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#4F91CD;
    }
#links a:hover {
    color:#244d71;
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-size:110%
    }
#links a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#4F91CD;
    }
#footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 35px 90px 35px 90px;
    color: #999;
    font-family: 'ChollUni',Helvetica, san-serif;
    position: absolute;
    left: 7px;
    top: 424px;
    }
```

THE HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
<title>Some Company Website</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="logo">
<center><img src="Images/logo.png"></center>
</div>
<div id="links">
<a href="http://www.SomeCompany.ca/mewebmail">Customer Email</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="http://www.SomeCompany.ca/meadmin">Webmail Administration</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div id="footer">
 Copyright 2013 Some Company &copy; All Rights Reserved
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for me all links works in Firefox, couldn't test in IE, dabblet dislike my IE :) are you sur you linke the right gist , cause HTML are different .

Comment: Here's a fiddle, it seems fine to me. Can you confirm it's broken for you? http://jsfiddle.net/CpmRG/

Comment: Ah, my bad.. It was just the visited link colour that threw me off.. that's embarrassing!